# In React.js array value is not passing properly via props?

Tags: ecmascript-6, reactjs

I have a react app that has two components one Customer and another called Tags. The Customer sends its state's tags value to Tags. As following:

Customer.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import Tags from "./Tags.jsx";

export default class Customer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {customer:''};
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const url = `http://localhost:3000/api/customers/${this.props.params.id}`
    fetch(url)
      .then(res=>res.json())
      .then(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          customer: data
        });
      })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          Company Name :{this.state.customer.companyName}
          Customer Name :{this.state.customer.name}
          Tags: <Tags tags={this.state.customer.tags} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Tags.jsx

```
import React from "react";

export default class Tags extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    let tags = this.props.tags.map(tag=>{
      return (<span>tag</span>);
    });
    return (
      <div>
        {tags}
      </div>
     );
  }
}
```

When I run the code I get, "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined(…)". If I replace below from Tags.jsx

```
let tags = this.props.tags.map(tag=>{
          return (<span>tag</span>);
        });
```

with

```
console.log(this.props.tags);
```

The output is an array. 
What is happening? I really do not understand. What can I do?

Comment: I think this error occurs while the http request is not done. So, tags is undefined because customer data is not there…

Comment: @micha149 but when I console.log(this.props.tags) it works properly.

Comment: `let tags = this.props.tags && this.props.tags.map(...)`

Comment: @InfiniteDev are you sure it doesn't log `undefined` first, then the tags array?

Comment: @pawel your code worked but I still do not understand how.

Comment: @InfiniteDev if `this.props.tags` is undefined (which it is before the API result arrives) the code doesn't call the `map` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the constructor of `Customer` you are defining the state of a `customer` as a string, not an object. You should change it to reflect the actual customer properties, ie:

```
 this.state = {customer: {name: '', tags: []}};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined, because of you're making an API call and the data isn't returned yet.

In your `Customer` component you can check the existance of `this.state.customer.tags` and if exist - then render the tags.

Somethling like that:

```
{ this.state.customer.tags ? <Tags tags={this.state.customer.tags} /> : null }
```